# Make http call on iOS while offline

Tags: ios, http, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

Perhaps I have been reading the wrong stuff, but one thing that all of the literatures that I have been reading seem to agree on is that: iOS does not allow background threads to run for longer than ten minutes. That seems to violate one of the greatest principles of app development: the internet should be invisible to your users. So here is a scenario.

A user is going through a tunnel or flying on an airplane, which causes no or unreliable network. At that instant, the user pulls out my email app, composes an email, and hits the send button.

Question: How do I the developer make sure that the email is sent when network becomes available? Of course I am using email as a general example, but in reality I am dealing with a very much simple http situation where my app needs to send a POST to my server.

**Side Note**: on android, I use Path’s priority job queue, which allows me to set it and forget it (i.e. as soon as there is network it sends my email).

**another Side Note**: I have been trying to use NSOperationQueue with AFNetworking, but does not do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve can be done using a background `NSURLSession`. While AFNetworking is based on NSURLSession I’m not quite sure if it can be used with a background session that runs while your app doesn’t. But you don’t really need this, NSURLSession is quite easy to use as is.

As a first step you need to create a session configuration for the background session:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "de.5sw.test")
config.isDiscretionary = true
config.waitsForConnectivity = true
```

The `isDiscretionary` property allows the system to decide when to perform the data transfer. `waitsForConnectivity` (available since iOS 11) makes the system wait if there is no internet connection instead of failing immediately.

With that configuration object you can create your URL session. The important part is to specify a delegate as the closure-based callbacks get lost when the app is terminated.

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

To perform your upload you ask the session to create an upload task and then resume it. For the upload task you first create your `URLRequest` that specifies the URL and all needed headers. The actual data you want to upload needs to be written to a file. If you provide it as a `Data` or stream object it cannot be uploaded after your app terminates.

```
let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileUrl)
task.resume()
```

To get notified of success or failure of your upload you need to implement the `URLSessionDataDelegate` method `urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)`. If error is `nil` the transfer was successful.

The final piece that is missing is to handle the events that happened while your app was not running. To do this you implement the method `application(_:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:)` in your app delegate. When the system decides that you need to handles some events for background transfers it launches your app in the background and calls this method.

In there you need first store the completion handler and then recreate your URLSession with the same configuration you used before. This then calls it’s delegate for the events you need to handle as usual. Once it is done with the events it calls the delegate method `urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)`. From there you need to call the completion handler that was passed to your app delegate.

The session configuration provides some more options:

- `timeoutIntervalForResource`: How long the system should try to perform your upload. Default is 7 days.
- `sessionSendsLaunchEvents`: If `false` the app will not be launched to handle events. They will be handled when the user opens the app manually. Defaults is `true`.

Here is a small sample project that shows how everything fits together: https://github.com/5sw/BackgroundUploadDemo

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to store the data internally and then you either need something which will cause the app to run in the background (but you shouldn't necessarily add something specially if you don't already have a reason to be doing it) or to wait until the user next brings the app to the foreground - then you can check for a network connection and make the call.

Note that e-mail is very different to a POST, because you can pass an e-mail off to the system mail app to send for you but you can't do exactly the same thing with a POST.

Consider looking also at [`NSURLSessionUploadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionUploadTask_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionUploadTask) if you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

In three words: you don't.

And that's actually a good thing. *I* certainly do not want to have to think and speculate about my last 20 apps, if they are still running in the background, using memory and battery and bandwidth. Furthermore, they would be killed if more memory is needed. How would the user be able to predict if it completed its task successfully? He can't, and need to open the app anyhow to check.

As for the email example, I'd go with showing the email as "pending" (i.e. not sent), until it transferred correctly. Make it obvious to the user that he has to come back later to fulfill the job.

While every developer thinks that his app has an extremely good reason for backgrounding, reality is, for the user in 99% it's just a pain. Can you say "task manager"? ;-)

Comment: Your app doesn't have to run to upload data in the background. That’s what the background NSURLSession is for. It gives the system the option to decide when is the best time for the upload. Your point about showing the pending state in the UI is good, of course. But you don’t have to make the user wait and watch the app while the upload is happening.

Comment: Yes, in 3 1/2 years things have changed a little.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pod that does pretty much this - https://cocoapods.org/pods/OfflineRequestManager. You'd have to do some work listening to delegate callbacks if you want to monitor whether the request is in a pending or completed/failed state, but we've been using it to ensure that requests go out in poor or no connectivity scenarios.

The simplest use case would look something like the following, though most actual cases (saving to disk, specific request data, etc.) will have a few more hoops to jump through:

```
import OfflineRequestManager

class SimpleRequest: OfflineRequest {
    func perform(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        doMyNetworkRequest(withCompletion: { response, error in
            handleResponse(response)
            completion(error)
        })
    }
}
///////
OfflineRequestManager.defaultManager(queueRequest: SimpleRequest())
```